# Marmalade Quick (lua) draw path

Tags: svg, lua, coordinates, marmalade, marmalade-quick

I'm writing an app in Marmalade quick (Lua) - a map, which is drawn from SVG file. In SVG I have polygons, polylines, matrix - it's easy. But I don't know what to do with paths'.

I've tried to convert them with php - no results. 
The one thing I found is converting paths' to coordinates with Javascript here http://forrst.com/posts/PHP_Convert_SVG_path_to_polygon-GDx, but that is not an option for me.

Maybe, I can draw a path in Marmalade Lua somehow, or convert it to coordinates?

Comment: Have you tried reading path documentation and parsing the commands? Correctly rendering stroke/fill can be very complex, but if you just want the outline its quite manageable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Comment: Hi, Thank You for the link! Yes, I've read the documentation, but couldn't find an answer. And yes, I need to fill the path with color, that is also a problem